# Access to physical ram addresses

Tags: winapi, assembly, operating-system, driver

while studying the principle of the work of cheats and anti-cheats, I became interested in how access to physical (not virtual) RAM addresses, for example, in windows, MmAllocateContiguousMemory is used to read from a physical address (in some examples)
But how does access to physical memory addresses works (I have not found any asm/C examples that does not use nativeApi or WinApi). I suppose that windows takes all control over memory and provides only shells for working with it - but in different OSs and in Windows, access to memory is also somehow implemented, how it works and is it possible to read physical memory without winapi / nativeApi [memtest works somehow))]

Comment: "But how does access to physical memory addresses works" - it's handled in hardware by the MMU.

Comment: See https://wiki.osdev.org/Category:Memory_management

Comment: @Dai If I understand the question correctly, the poster wants to know if there is an API for accessing a physical address directly - just like `/dev/mem` does under Linux.

Comment: Note that physical address space contains memory-mapped IO regions (MMIO), device memory, and ROM, as well as the physical RAM.

Answer (score 6):

When an OS boot up it enables virtual memory. From that point on, every access to memory (address space) goes through the MMU of the CPU.
Controlling the MMU is a privileged operation, only privileged code (read: the OS) can change the MMU configuration.
The MMU configuration controls what physical address a virtual address is mapped to.

When you ask Windows to "read" a range of physical memory, it actually sets up the MMU so that the returned *virtual* range maps to the given physical memory.
You then read the *virtual* memory as usual.
Virtual memory is *not* something along the side of physical memory, it is *on top* of physical memory.
It's always there.

So a user space program cannot access physical memory without the help of the OS, the CPU will always use virtual memory once enabled.
In fact, this would pose a security risk as it bypasses the security mechanism virtual memory provides on top of physical memory (memory isolation).